# flutter error:Property 'buffer' cannot be accessed on 'ByteData?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PY0e.png)

I am facing errors shown in image while running any flutter app in VSCODE as well as ANDROID STUDIO.Previously all the apps used to run successfully but now even the pre-defined main.dart file of new flutter project is not running

This is error I m facing in VSCODE
"/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:667:24: Error: Property 'buffer' cannot be accessed on 'ByteData?'
because it is potentially null.

- 'ByteData' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
  Try accessing using ?. instead.
  return decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp6oh.png)

Comment: Are you using a fork of a repo locally?

Comment: Ya I tried to run code copied from github but deleted it when it showeD error after that even if I try to run a new project it's showing this error

Comment: Can you include your codes too please